# I can't get Selenium code to open a tab in an existing browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get Selenium to work in Chrome as an existing browser and my code is pretty simple I just do not know why it won't work. (PS I use a Mac)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrx8FSEo9lk&t=161s&ab_channel=Mukeshotwani

here is the link to the YouTube video I was trying to follow

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/adeelsyed/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64',chrome_options=opt)

url = 'https://monkeytype.com/'
driver.get(url)

print("test")
```

so they before I run this code I type this into terminal
`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=8989`

and terminal opens up a chrome tab, but then when I click run nothing happens, it doesn't print out "test"

instead it gives this really big error

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/adeelsyed/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64',chrome_options=opt)
/Users/adeelsyed/Desktop/Summer Grind Projects/UpdatedMonkType.py:9: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/adeelsyed/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64',chrome_options=opt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adeelsyed/Desktop/Summer Grind Projects/UpdatedMonkType.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/adeelsyed/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64',chrome_options=opt)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:8989
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000104da78ac chromedriver + 4257964
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000104d9ff40 chromedriver + 4226880
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001049dc854 chromedriver + 280660
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001049cb004 chromedriver + 208900
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a08550 chromedriver + 460112
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a017bc chromedriver + 432060
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a3f3dc chromedriver + 685020
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a3ec08 chromedriver + 683016
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a0b98c chromedriver + 473484
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a0c98c chromedriver + 477580
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d66900 chromedriver + 3991808
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d6a354 chromedriver + 4006740
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d6a940 chromedriver + 4008256
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d7033c chromedriver + 4031292
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d6af34 chromedriver + 4009780
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d43490 chromedriver + 3847312
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d889f4 chromedriver + 4131316
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d88b4c chromedriver + 4131660
18  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d99230 chromedriver + 4198960
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018196606c _pthread_start + 148
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000181960e2c thread_start + 8
```

What is wrong with my code?

Anyways I tried using a different executable_path='/Users/adeelsyed/Downloads/chromedriver_mac64\ 2/chromedriver' because that is what the terminal spat out, but that did not work either, and I really just have no clue what is wrong here.

Comment: `opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")` Why are you using this option?

Comment: @JohnGordon To be honest I don't know it was just the guy in the tutorial was using it... is there a better option?

Comment: Why are you using any special options at all?

Comment: Because I want the selenium to run in an existing chrome browser

Comment: And how did you think an option named `debuggerAddress` would help with that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know I was following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrx8FSEo9lk&t=161s&ab_channel=Mukeshotwani) and he said that you can run it if you run chrome as a debugger, that way you can access that chrome with selenium

Answer (score 2):

The same problem I was facing a month ago when I need to test multiple apps in a single browser. I had to login every time before the test and it was very irritating.

I solved it after investing 2 and a half days. Let me share the solution with you.

You don't need to run any command manually before run the script. Just follow the steps below:

**Step 1**. Make sure you have installed the latest version of **selenium** and **webdriver-manager** using this command:

`pip install selenium webdriver-manager`.

**Step 2**. Make Sure You have installed the latest version of Chrome.

**Solution:**

Here is the code tested and working fine on a Windows machine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driverPath = ChromeDriverManager().install()
subprocess.Popen(["start","chrome","--remote-debugging-port=9089","--user-data-dir=" + os.getcwd() + "/chromeProfile",],shell=True)
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9089")
service = Service(executable_path=driverPath)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,options=options)
```

Now You can open any url using above driver instance.

```
url = 'https://monkeytype.com/'
driver.get(url)

print("test")
```

When you run this script it will create a folder name "chromeProfile" in your current working directory. All the browser data and history will save into that folder. You will not need to login again and agian for the same web app.

That's it ..

Let me know if you still facing any issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Selfdev.py! However I am getting this error when I run it
[WDM] - Downloading: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 7.40M/7.40M [00:00<00:00, 48.5MB/s]
chrome: start: command not found
Also, I had to import subprocess, Popen, and os. BTW I am on Mac it that affects anything. Is there something I have to download?

Comment: yes, this will not work on the Mac I think. As I mention I tested it on a Windows machine. You can configure it for Mac by changing this line `subprocess.Popen(["start","chrome","--remote-debugging-port=9089","--user-data-dir=" + os.getcwd() + "/chromeProfile",],shell=True)`.

Comment: @AdeelSyed I will update the existing answer or add a new one for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

**For Mac**

As we know `subprocess` module uses our OS terminal to execute the commands.

So, if you are on Mac then the above code will not work on your machine due to the differences in terminal commands.

All you need to change the `subprocess` command with respect to your OS. The main purpose of this line of code is to open Chrome in remote debugging mode using any open-free port (9089) so that Selenium can detect and bind the driver with the opened Chrome instance.

To convert the code for launching Chrome with remote debugging enabled on a Mac, you can use the `subprocess.run` function instead. Here's the modified code:

```
import subprocess
import os

chrome_command = [
    "open",
    "-a",
    "Google Chrome",
    "--args",
    "--remote-debugging-port=9089",
    "--user-data-dir=" + os.getcwd() + "/chromeProfile",
]

subprocess.run(chrome_command)
```

Let me explain the above code:

- `subprocess.run` is used instead of `subprocess.Popen`. This
  simplifies the code and provides a more straightforward way to
  execute the command.
- The command to open Chrome on macOS is "`open`". It is used in
  combination with the `-a` flag to specify the application to open,
  which is "`Google Chrome`" in this case.
- The `--args` flag is used to indicate that the following arguments
  should be passed to the application.
- "`--remote-debugging-port=9089`" and "`--user-data-dir=`" + `os.getcwd()` +
  "`/chromeProfile`" arguments remain the same, enabling remote debugging
  on port 9089 and using a separate user profile stored in the
  "chromeProfile" folder within the current working directory.

By using these modifications, the code should successfully launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled on a Mac.

**Note**
All the remaining lines of code will be the same as in the above answer.

Comment: Thank you so much again for the answer @Selfdev.py . So after running the code it opened chrome with me logged in, which is great! However it wasn't getting the url, and after like 30 seconds it gives this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9089
from chrome not reachable`. I looked it up and I tried using 9222, 8989(which is the debugging port I used to type in the terminal to open a tab in debugging mode),127.0.0.1:5000, my local ip, and none of them worked. Is there a specific host per computer I can find?

Comment: Hi, mostly this error appears due to a busy port in your machine. Try to use any other different port rather than what you mentioned here. Make sure you change the port in both places in a subprocess command and in selenium bind code `add_experimental_option`. I hope it will let you visit the URL in the browser.

Comment: @AdeelSyed did it worked for you?